# Height of input box on Contact 7 form

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, contact-form

I am trying to reduce the height of the "Your Message" input box on the Contact 7 form on this page: https://www.nycofficesuites.com/new/office-space-vertical/

I've tried the following (with different heights so I can see which one is working) but nothing is working.  Thanks for your help.

```
.wpcf7-textarea {
height: 80px;
}

.wpcf7 input[type=text] {
height:10px !important;

}

textarea {
   height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: If you inspect the element, you'll see that it has `min-height` set. So instead of `.wpcf7-textarea{ height: 80px; }`, use `.wpcf7-textarea{ min-height: 80px; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reducing the min-height of this class below

```
.form-box textarea, .wpcf7 .wpcf7-textarea {
    border: medium none;
    display: block;
    min-height: 97px; //REDUCE THIS
    padding: 12px 10px;
    width: 96.6%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `min-height` is overruling your height definition.  You'll want to size down min-height in addition to height:

```
min-height: 30px;
height: 30px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `min-height` on your `.form-box textarea, .wpcf7 .wpcf7-textarea` this is preventing your css `height` from been applied to the `textarea`.